# Finding a maximum order degree-constrained subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

For a given (unweighted) graph G(V,E) with an integer d > 1, how do I find a connected subgraph H of G with maximum |V(H)| and satisfying ∆(H) ≤ d (i.e. subgraph H is connected with the maximum number of nodes in which degree of node in H is bounded by d).

Could anyone please suggest an approximation algorithm to find the subgraph H which satisfies the above constraints?